# Why can't I use an actual class in LINQ-to-SQL join method?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

I am trying to do a LINQ join in C# (using EntityFramework Core 3.1.13) that uses a class in the key selector.

For example:

```
public class KeyClass {
       public int Key { get; set; }    
}


using (var Context = new ...Context()) {

var Query = Context.Table1.Join(Context.Table2,x => new KeyClass () { Key = x.ID }, x => new KeyClass() { Key = x.ID2 }, (x,y) => new { x, y });

}
```

It doesn't work when I use the KeyClass - I get an error stating the LINQ expression cannot be translated.

But if I use an anonymous type instead, it works fine:

```
using (var Context = new ...Context()) {

var Query = Context.Table1.Join(Context.Table2,x => new  { Key = x.ID }, x => new { Key = x.ID2 }, (x,y) => new { x, y });

}
```

I cannot use the anonymous type in my case because I want to be able to build the join at runtime dynamically and will need to use an emitted type for the key selector as it may have multiple keys and different types.

Comment: You would have to ask the EF dev team why. As a guess, making a class here is not particularly useful. It's meant to be a transient object that only exists for the lifetime of the query.

Comment: It is useful for my particular application -- I've indicated why.

Comment: Also worth noting that if this was just Linq and not EF, using a class would break it anyway since the default comparer would be testing for reference equality.

Comment: Not if EF is doing a value comparison on the individual keys like it is doing for an anonymous type.  There has to be a way to dynamically build this with multiple keys.

Comment: As a note, using a tuple works, but still limiting

Comment: Does it work as a `struct` rather than a `class` perhaps?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  Appreciate the suggestion though.

Comment: It's just an `Expression` so you could manually create that.

Comment: Maybe pulling out the expression like `Func<dynamic, KeyClass> outerKeySelector = x => new KeyClass() { Key = x["Id"] }; Func<dynamic, KeyClass> innerKeySelector = x => new KeyClass() { Key = x["Id2"] };` and then in the join method: `.Join(Context.Table2,outerKeySelector,innerKeySelector,...)`

Comment: That won't translate - you have to use System.Linq.Expression in an IQueryable for it to be translated in LINQ-to-SQL.

Comment: DavidG, you can't create an anonymous type using System.Linq.Expression.  To create a NewExpression (before doing the MemberInit binding), you must specify a class.

Comment: Thinking about this a little more, you could use anonymous types, but you would have to define them beforehand unfortunately.

Comment: For the record, what EF Core version are we talking about?

Comment: I'm using 3.1.13

Comment: EF is not Linq to SQL.  Link to SQL is an old tool that was replaced by EF.  The language that EF uses is called "Linq to Entities."

Comment: EFC 5.0+ adds some other possibilities. In EFC 3.x just use tuples. If you want to know why, look at the expression `new  { Key = x.ID }` - looks like `MemberInit`, isn't it? But it isn't - plain `New` constructor call, and EFC is just taking the constructor arguments in order (all they need is `x.ID`). The same is for tuples - constructor call with the knowledge that ordered arguments represent the class content.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the 5.0+ new "possibilities"?

Comment: Support for `Dictionary<string, object>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because the EFC translator only supports `Expression.New` (C# `new`) constructor call with arguments rather than `Expression.MemberInit` (C# object initializer) for join keys.

Both anonymous types and tuples fall into the first category (event though syntactically anonymous type allocations looks like object initializer, in fact it is a constructor call of the compiler generated class - similar to the C#9 record declaration), while your class doesn't.

Knowing all that, the solution is actually quite simple - just add and use constructor to the class, e.g.

```
public class KeyClass
{
    public KeyClass(int key) => Key = key;
    public int Key { get; }    
}
```

or in C#9

```
public record KeyClass(int Key);
```

Now this works (translates)

```
var Query = Context.Table1.Join(Context.Table2,
    x => new KeyClass(x.ID), x => new KeyClass(x.ID2),
    (x, y) => new { x, y });
```